# Map Windows paths to Linux paths for VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, filenames

I am trying to sync my VirtualBox machines between Linux + Windows. However, the configuration file below is shown in Windows directory format. My Linux location is `/media/large/VirtualBox`, my Windows is `D:\VirtualBox`. Is there any way to map `D:\` to `/media/large`?

EDIT: I also need to AUTOMATICALLY change `\` to `/`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.12-windows">
  <Global>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/DetailsPageBoxes" value="general,system,preview,display,storage,audio,network,usb,sharedFolders,description"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/" value="go=Linux,go=Mac OSX,go=Virus Tests,go=Windows"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/Linux" value="m=961169b7-5d37-4b29-b4bf-c16c39ddda6a,m=321fafcc-9a84-4303-a8f6-777a54bbb420,m=41d67265-baf7-4b07-a98f-163012e4c1ef,m=48f12f20-604b-4977-b415-ca6ca4680c0f,m=e6b39bc1-0de8-49df-8cd1-92250840617e,m=0b09bc8a-8aa9-41e0-b79a-faef029003b0,m=9c6fc622-b0c1-47c8-b2b6-3a0a723257bd"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/Mac OSX" value="m=9136bf28-622b-4d5c-9dac-5c46529aff7b"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/Virus Tests" value="m=be4f52c0-4d86-445d-bf49-65d86bd1c8de"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/Windows" value="m=7ec90f6d-3bf2-4d96-912c-67283315a62b,m=d89443fc-2e4b-4870-a0d4-bf99b2d2a1f5,m=20a56fc1-4acf-436a-a3b1-6c79d1786911,m=4eecddd5-53d6-403f-9e11-3f91be2ea0f7"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/HideDescriptionForWizards" value="NewVM"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/HostScreenSaverDisabled" value="false"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Input/AutoCapture" value="true"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Input/HostKeyCombination" value="163"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastItemSelected" value="m=Mac OSX 10.12 Sierra"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastWindowPosition" value="0,23,1920,1027,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentFolderCD" value="D:/OS"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentFolderHD" value="D:/Virtual Box"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentListCD" value="D:\OS\Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso,D:\OS\Windows 10 x64 Insider Preview.iso"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentListHD" value="D:\Virtual Box\UbuntuPartition.vmdk,D:\Virtual Box\UbuntuPartition-pt.vmdk,D:\Virtual Box\USB.vmdk,D:\Virtual Box\Windows\Windows 7\Windows 7.vdi,D:\Virtual Box\Windows 7.vdi"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SplitterSizes" value="638,1277"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SuppressMessages" value="remindAboutAutoCapture,remindAboutMouseIntegration"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/UpdateCheckCount" value="8"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/UpdateDate" value="never"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <MachineRegistry>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{961169b7-5d37-4b29-b4bf-c16c39ddda6a}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Linux/Debian/Debian.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{321fafcc-9a84-4303-a8f6-777a54bbb420}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Linux/Kali Linux/Kali Linux.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{41d67265-baf7-4b07-a98f-163012e4c1ef}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Linux/Linux Mint Mate/Linux Mint Mate.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{48f12f20-604b-4977-b415-ca6ca4680c0f}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Linux/Ubuntu 16.04/Ubuntu 16.04.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{9136bf28-622b-4d5c-9dac-5c46529aff7b}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Mac OSX/Mac OSX 10.12 Sierra/Mac OSX 10.12 Sierra.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{be4f52c0-4d86-445d-bf49-65d86bd1c8de}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Virus Tests/Windows XP - Infected/Windows XP - Infected.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{20a56fc1-4acf-436a-a3b1-6c79d1786911}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Windows/Windows 8/Windows 8.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{4eecddd5-53d6-403f-9e11-3f91be2ea0f7}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Windows/Windows 10 Insider Preview/Windows 10 Insider Preview.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{7ec90f6d-3bf2-4d96-912c-67283315a62b}" src="D:/Virtual Box/Windows/Windows XP/Windows XP.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{d89443fc-2e4b-4870-a0d4-bf99b2d2a1f5}" src="D:\Virtual Box\Windows\Windows 7\Windows 7.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{e6b39bc1-0de8-49df-8cd1-92250840617e}" src="D:\Virtual Box/Linux\Fedora\Fedora.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{0b09bc8a-8aa9-41e0-b79a-faef029003b0}" src="D:\Virtual Box/Linux\Gparted\Gparted.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{9c6fc622-b0c1-47c8-b2b6-3a0a723257bd}" src="D:\Virtual Box/Linux\Ubuntu Partition\Ubuntu Partition.vbox"/>
    </MachineRegistry>
    <NetserviceRegistry>
      <DHCPServers>
        <DHCPServer networkName="HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" IPAddress="192.168.56.100" networkMask="255.255.255.0" lowerIP="192.168.56.101" upperIP="192.168.56.254" enabled="1"/>
      </DHCPServers>
    </NetserviceRegistry>
    <SystemProperties defaultMachineFolder="D:\Virtual Box" defaultHardDiskFormat="VDI" VRDEAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" webServiceAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" LogHistoryCount="3" exclusiveHwVirt="false"/>
    <USBDeviceFilters/>
  </Global>
</VirtualBox>
```

Comment: Yes, there is.  However the question is out of scope for this forum.    Suggest you ask it in the Superusers forum

Comment: @Thomas Use backticks to format code. Asterisks are for italics.

Comment: Please do not post ask us to look at things on external sites. Your question must be self-contained. I've fixed your question, in the future please post the content directly.

Comment: @Gilles Will try to do in future.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 why? This is perfectly on topic here. First because it is a simple text parsing question and second because it is also *nix related. If something is *nix related, the fact that is *also* Windows-related doesn't make it off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid having two VirtualBox configuration files but share the same one, there are two sets of conversions to consider.

1. You have Windows paths with backslash `\` between folders. For example, `D:\OS\Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso`
2. You have Windows paths with forward slash `/` between folders. For example, `D:/Virtual Box/Linux/Kali Linux/Kali Linux.vbox`

In both cases the paths start with `D:`

You can fix the path starting point with a symbolic link placed strategically in the directory from which you run VirtualBox. In addition, it's possible to fix up the backslashes in the configuration file with a repeatable transform:

```
ln -s /media/large 'D:'
cp -p vbox.xml vbox.xml.old && tr '\\' / <vbox.xml.old >vbox.xml
```

If you want to avoid fixing up the VirtualBox configuration file itself it gets a bit harder, but it's not impossible. Ideally you'll go back and check on the Windows side to see if you can provide forward slashed paths. If not, a careful further application of symbolic links may help. Here is an example of the sort of thing you'll have to apply:

```
ln -s 'D:'/OS/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso 'D:\OS\Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso'
```

Notice that I've quoted the target link name and left the backslashes verbatim. This will create a name that superfically may appear to be a Windows filename path apparently including folders, but is actually just a UNIX filename containing necessary backslashes.

Comment: @Modelmat if you follow my suggestion there is no conversion; you can just use the same file.

Comment: @Modelmat you don't need to convert the file if you follow my suggestions!

Comment: @Modelmat CAPITALS are understood as shouting and are considered ruse. Please don't shout at the people trying to help you. Now, Roaima has given you a great solution that only needs to be run once and you don't need to change the file. Yet, you still talk about "automating". Instead of yelling, explain clearly what kind of automation you need. Preferably by asking a new question.

Comment: @Modelmat I don't understand what you don't like about the two solutions I've offered. You cannot have a file that is magically two different things at the same time; you either have to transform the file or its environment. I've offered you both. Apply the chosen transforms just before you start VirtualBox on the Linux system and you'll be set.

Comment: @Modelmat pleased you're happy with the solution. You might like to review your comments and delete those that are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use any text-processing tool. With `sed`, for example:

```
sed 's|D:\|/media/large|g' file.win > file.nix
```

Comment: Can this be automated?

Comment: @Modelmat can what be automated? What do you mean by "automated"? What should be done automatically and what do you mean by "automatically"? Every day? On ever new file? On every file on the system? Every Wednesday if the moon is full? Please explain.

Comment: Automatically on new file change, to the same file. I assume it would be just a bash script?

Comment: @Modelmat that's a completely separate question. Please post it as a new question. Also, search the site for `inotify`, that's what you'll probably need to use.

Comment: That is not a separate question. I need to use without having to constantly do something. (like the answer)