# Why Does `'ln -s /directory 'D:'` Work Like It Does?

Tags: windows, directory, filenames, ln

So, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366890/map-windows-paths-to-linux-paths-for-virtualbox/), `'ln -s /directory 'D:'` maps the windows `D:` location to a Linux style directory.

However, as far as I know, this goes against the Linux naming system. Why does Linux allow the use of Windows style directory starters in the `ln` command?

Comment: Since this is on Windows, it has nothing to do with Linux.  The Windows POSIX API must have special handling for such names and creates the symlink in the \DosDevices NT kernel directory, which lets win32 applications treat it like a dos drive letter.

Comment: @psusi So windows the entire time is basically using `ln -s` for the `C:`, `D:`, etc. drives to work and function? In essence, does it use Linux-style path names (excluding `/` and `'\'` (Like mentioned below?)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Linux-style path names".  Internally the NT kernel has a namespace containing various objects including Devices, which are normally in the \Devices directory iirc, and the win32 subsystem looks for "dos drives" in \DosDevices, which are symlinks to devices under \Devices, and the rest of the file path is appended to that.  So when you say "C:\foo\bar.txt", win32 asks the kernel for \DosDevices\C:\foo\bar.txt, which translates to \Devices\PhysicalDisk0\foo\bar.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works because `D:` is a valid directory name in Linux (and POSIX in general). It has no significance as far as Linux is concerned.

(Some programs will treat certain directories named like this in a special way, in the appropriate directory; for example, Wine expects directories like this in the `dosdevices` directory inside a Wine prefix. But that’s specific to Wine, not something enforced by Linux.)

Comment: So Linux just goes "`D:` is a symbolic link to `/directory`, so this is where it shall go? There is no specific place `D:` is actually at, just a symbolic link?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. It would be the same if you’d specified `blah` from the kernel’s perspective; in the example, VirtualBox asks for `D:`, which in this scenario is a symlink (but could be anything at all).

Comment: Thankyou! That clears things up nicely! (Funny idea - symlink to `blah`.)

Answer (score 1):

The `:` character has no special meaning in a *nix filename. Any characters are allowed except NUL and `/` (several characters need to be escaped when entered into or piped into commands, especially spaces and newlines, but they are still legal).

In your example, `D:` is just a regular file!